# What front-end (browser) frameworks completely abstract the browser?

Tags: language-agnostic

Cappuccino is one.

> "With Cappuccino, you don't need to
>   know HTML. You'll never write a line
>   of CSS. You don't ever have interact
>   with DOM."

What other front-end frameworks completely abstract away DOM/HTML/JavaScript/CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another:
http://qooxdoo.org

They say:

> "No HTML, CSS nor DOM knowledge is needed."

and:

> "No HTML has to be used and augmented to define the interface. The qooxdoo developer does not even have to know CSS  to style the interface. "

Comment: Accepting my own answer unless someone finds a more exhaustive list or other good options.

Answer (score 0):

[GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/overview.html)

**NOTE**: if you need deeper use of resources like css/html/native-javascript you could do it, what I think is valuable for a front-end framework.

Comment: GWT requires CSS to style the app. So it doesn't count. From the GWT documentation: 
`"GWT provides very few Java methods directly related to style. Rather, we encourage you to define styles in Cascading Style Sheets. When it comes to styling web applications, CSS is ideal. In addition to cleanly separating style from application logic, this division of labor helps applications load and render more quickly, consume less memory, and even makes them easier to tweak during edit/debug cycles because there's no need to recompile for style tweaks. "`

Comment: @z5h But you can use it without defining styles in CSS at all. As I pointed, it allows you to use it rather than to have to.